# Zabbix Upgrade - database upgrade failed 5.0.8 to 6.2

Tags: zabbix

I am doing to upgrade Zabbix 5.0 to 6.2 within old data but it's failed when upgrade database. how to fix it? why happing this error?

error:

524255:20220727:120501.638 database upgrade failed
524259:20220727:120513.877 Starting Zabbix Server. Zabbix 6.2.0rc3 (revision 0e0e9f05882).
524259:20220727:120513.877 ****** Enabled features ******
524259:20220727:120513.877 SNMP monitoring:           YES
524259:20220727:120513.877 IPMI monitoring:           YES
524259:20220727:120513.877 Web monitoring:            YES
524259:20220727:120513.877 VMware monitoring:         YES
524259:20220727:120513.877 SMTP authentication:       YES
524259:20220727:120513.877 ODBC:                      YES
524259:20220727:120513.877 SSH support:               YES
524259:20220727:120513.877 IPv6 support:              YES
524259:20220727:120513.877 TLS support:               YES
524259:20220727:120513.877 ******************************
524259:20220727:120513.877 using configuration file: /etc/zabbix/zabbix_server.conf
524259:20220727:120513.887 current database version (mandatory/optional): 05010052/05010052
524259:20220727:120513.887 required mandatory version: 06010097
524259:20220727:120513.887 starting automatic database upgrade
524259:20220727:120513.887 [Z3005] query failed: [1050] Table 'role' already exists [create table role (
`roleid` bigint unsigned not null,
`name` varchar(255) default '' not null,
`type` integer default '0' not null,
`readonly` integer default '0' not null,
primary key (roleid)
) engine=innodb]
524259:20220727:120513.887 database upgrade failed